# debounceTime makes form control run twice

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using `debounceTime` to get a list in a dropdown, so far everything works just fine I typed three characters and it triggers api call return to me a list, but the problem is when I choose one item in the list the `valueChanges` of from Control causes this to call again, which is unnecessary. How to prevent this?

Here is my code:

```
this.myForm.controls['control'].valueChanges.pipe(
      filter(text => text.length > 2),
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((value: string) => {
        this.getItem(value);
});
```

Comment: You need a flag to say if the value comes from the user input or user selecting from the list returned by API. And depending on the flag, the `valueChanges` should continue or ignore. But anyway I personally use the `Typeahead` from bootstrap, or angular powered bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better to give a Id for the form control that you are looking for text inputs like bellow:

```
<input type="text" id="inputText">
```

Then only use that form control to fetch the data when typing on it like bellow example:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const inputText = document.getElementById('inputText');
    const typeahead = fromEvent(inputText, 'input').pipe(
      map((e: KeyboardEvent) => (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).value),
      filter(text => text.length > 2),
      debounceTime(10),
      distinctUntilChanged()
   );

    typeahead.subscribe(data => {
      this.getItem(data);
    });
  }
```

Then it will only fire when you are typing on that input form controller

[Working DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1quxk)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on angular then you shouldn't use getElementById() instead use even keyup, keydown, blur to fire your method like:

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" (keyup)="fetchList()">

fetchList(){
distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((value: string) => {
        this.getItem(value);
}
```

You can add debounce before calling your api